# Take data from last 14 days and compare with the latest 7 days

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MySQL table:

```
typ | user | data | value

typ = what type of data 
user = whos the user
data = date the data was inserted
value = value inserted
```

So this table is updated automatically in my cronjob. Usually one user will have multiply rows in this table, since it will insert a new row for each new day and update the current row if the date is the same as today.

I need to take data from the latest 14 days and compare them with the data from the latest 7 days.

```
7 | admin | 2013/09/22 | 3412
7 | admin | 2013/09/23 | 1241
7 | admin | 2013/09/24 | 2419
and so on...
```

This is how the structure is.

How can I, with PHP, get the data from the latest 14 days? And then from the latest 7 days?

I'm unsure on how to do this.

Comment: You should post a code you tried already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where curdate() - interval 14 day >= data 

select * from your_table
where curdate() - interval 7 day >= data
```